# How to insert an update query in ReactiveMongoRepository

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, rx-java2, spring-webflux

I'm new to reactive programming, I'm doing a CRUD in reactive programming, my question is how to use findOneAndUpdate in a query of the ReactiveMongoRepository and to return the updated document.

```java
@Repository
public interface CompanyRepository extends ReactiveMongoRepository<CompanyEntity, String> {

 @Query("{'code': ?0 } , { $set: {'status': true}}, {new: true }")
    Mono<CompanyEntity> updateDeleteLogic(String code);

}
```

I need to execute this query to give a logical elimination to the bd

```js
db.getCollection('company').findOneAndUpdate({'code': 'dni-33333333'},{$set: {'status': false}}, {new:true})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@Query("{'code': ?0 }")
@Update("{ $set: {'status': true}}, {new: true }")
Mono<CompanyEntity> updateDeleteLogic(String code);
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.